# How to pass data to another view, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im wanto to pass some values from some textbox i have in view1 and need those values in view2 how can i achive this. In view2 I have user controller

UserForm.aspx

```
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
            <div style="height: 363px">

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtName" Text="This field is required"
          ForeColor="Red" runat="server"><img src="Images/icon_error_white.gif" alt="Error" />         </asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Phone"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtPhone" Text="This field is required"
            ForeColor="Red" runat="server"><img src="Images/icon_error_white.gif" alt="Error" /></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Doc"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDoc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtDoc" Text="This field is required"
                    ForeColor="Red" runat="server"><img src="Images/icon_error_white.gif" alt="Error" /></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Style="z-index: 1; left: 16px; top: 176px; position: absolute"
                    Text="Create" />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
            <MSD:User ID="User1" runat="server" />
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</form>
```

UserForm.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool Name= String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text);
    bool Phone= String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPhone.Text);
    bool Doc= String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDoc.Text);


    MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2);
}
public string Name
{
    get { return txtName.Text; }
}
public string Phone
{
    get { return txtPhone.Text; }
}
public string Doc
{
    get { return Doc.Text; }
}
```

UserControll.ascx

```
   <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Doc" runat="server" Text="Doc"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDoc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
        <hr />
    </div>
```

I need to pass the text on view1 to view2 witch is the controller

I'm new in ASP.NET, and web programming in general, so any help and comments is useful 
*Note: Im not using MVC model

Comment: Could you specify the following: Is the text in the part you labeled "controller" also within UserForm.aspx? If not, could you specify what their urls are? Also, why are you calling them view1 and view2, when you also note you are NOT using the MVC application architecture? In .aspx world, typically we call things like UserForm.aspx "pages", which contain both display and application logic. MVC tries to separate that into views and controllers, but that separation does not exist in .aspx and using the terms makes the question sound confusing.

Comment: @welegan, he's using MultiView control...

Comment: Edited "Controller" name, when using " <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">" with "<asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">" View1 is the default id for it, like i said im new to asp.net, from what i have read this type of "View" is different from the view term in MVC model

Comment: @walther doh, thanks for pointing that out. MoralesJosue: thanks for editing it, usercontrol makes more sense.